Hamiltonian in Non-Linear Optics
I want to know why we add an additional term known as hermitian conjugate in the hamiltonian of many non-linear optical processes like SPDC. For example the in the equation below,


You add it so that the Hamiltonian is hermitian.

Reason 1 : in order to make the Hamiltonian hermitian and ensure the unitarity of the evolution operator in consequence. Reason 2 : the interaction term $\hat{a}_1^\dagger\hat{a}_2^\dagger\hat{a}_0$ means that the mode 0 is split into modes 1 and 2; the reverse process will be represented by the hermitian conjugate.
